# windows command alias failure

Tags: windows, shell, command-prompt

I am trying to set some command aliases on my command shell. I seem to remember doing this on another computer without any issues some time ago. Today, I followed the instructions here:
http://www.displayobject.fr/2010/03/07/create-cmd-aliases-in-windows/

My file that contains my aliases was made in notepad++ and is called aliases.bat. It get's installed correctly in the registry with the command:

```
reg add "hkcu\software\microsoft\command processor" /v Autorun /t reg_sz /d c:\Users\dmedine\aliases.bat
```

I know it's there, because I can see it. But, when I open a new shell simply prints the line that I want it to run and the shell is non-responsive[image]

Is this some weird line ending issue?

The file is just one line:

```
doskey ls=dir $*
```

I just tried opening a command prompt and running the code above, same stalling behavior. At least I know it has nothing to do with the registry.

Comment: If you suspect a line ending issue have you checked what the line endings on that file are and ensuring that they are DOS line endings?

Comment: No. I haven't figured out how to do this yet.

Comment: You should be able to do both of those things with Notepad++ in the menus or file properties or some-such (I don't use it but I know it can do it).

Comment: Just checked (there's an option in the edit menu on notepad++). Windows endings.

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out that calling doskey was causing an infinite loop (hence the hang.) I came across this:
http://nerdanswer.com/answer.php?q=336122
This person reported the same thing, but running cd first fixed it. I get the same behavior. I simply modified my alias.bat file so that it does a quick cd first. Hunky Dory, but confusing.